# How to make the drawing better?

Tags: assembly, x86, tasm, dosbox

I am creating right now paint app.
I've created the drawing feature, but unfortunately, it is not painting me
all my pixel trough the movement of the mouse. (I added a screenshot for it)

This is part of my code  (The drawing feature only):

```
  proc init
push ax

;graphical mode. 40x25. 256 colours. 320x200 pixels. 1 page.
mov ax, 0
mov al, 13h 
int 10h


pop ax
ret
endp init


proc cls
push ax
push bx
push cx
push dx


; scoll up for cleaning the screen
mov bx ,0
mov al, 200
mov ah, 6h
int 10h

pop dx
pop cx
pop bx
pop ax


ret
endp cls

;----------------------------------------------------------------

; Set the pixel at given position to given color

; INPUT

; ax - x position

; bx - y position

; cx - color

;----------------------------------------------------------------
proc set_pixel


mov ah, 0ch
int 10h     ; set pixel. 


ret
endp set_pixel




proc draw_horizontal_line
;----------------------------------------------------------------

; Draw horizontal line

; INPUT


; bx - end column (cx)

; cx - column

; dx - row

;----------------------------------------------------------------

@@wall:
call set_pixel
inc cx
cmp cx, bx
je @@done
jmp @@wall
@@done:
ret
endp draw_horizontal_line

proc draw_vertical_line
;----------------------------------------------------------------

; Draw vertical line

; INPUT


; bx - end row (dx)

; cx - column

; dx - row

;----------------------------------------------------------------


@@wall:
call set_pixel
inc dx
cmp dx, bx
je @@done
jmp @@wall
@@done:
ret
endp draw_vertical_line


proc draw_left_wall

mov cx , 5
mov dx , 20
mov bx, 190

mov al, 0100b

call draw_vertical_line

ret 
endp draw_left_wall

proc draw_right_wall

mov cx , 250
mov dx , 20
mov bx, 191

mov al, 0100b

call draw_vertical_line

ret 
endp draw_right_wall

proc draw_top_wall

mov cx , 5
mov dx , 20
mov bx, 250

mov al, 0100b

call draw_horizontal_line


ret 
endp draw_top_wall

proc draw_bottom_wall
mov al, 0100b
mov cx , 5
mov dx , 190
mov bx, 250


call draw_horizontal_line

ret 
endp draw_bottom_wall

proc exit_button
mov al, 0100b
mov cx , 1
mov dx , 1
mov bx, 6

call draw_horizontal_line

mov al, 0100b
mov cx , 1
mov dx , 6
mov bx, 6

call draw_horizontal_line

mov cx , 1
mov dx , 1
mov bx, 6

mov al, 0100b

call draw_horizontal_line

mov cx , 6
mov dx , 1
mov bx, 6

mov al, 0100b

call draw_horizontal_line

endp exit_button

proc draw_inner_background


mov dx , 190



@@looper:
sub dx, 1

call white_line

cmp dx, 21
je @@done
jmp @@looper

@@done:

ret
endp draw_inner_background

proc draw_out_background


mov dx , 200


@@looper:
sub dx, 1

call background_color

cmp dx, 0
je @@done
jmp @@looper

@@done:

ret
endp draw_out_background

proc background_color
push cx
push dx
push bx
mov cx , 0
mov bx, 320

mov al, 1110b

call draw_horizontal_line
pop bx
pop dx
pop cx
ret
endp background_color


proc white_line
push cx
push dx
push bx
mov cx , 6
mov bx, 250

mov al, 1111b

call draw_horizontal_line
pop bx
pop dx
pop cx
ret
endp white_line



proc resetAndShowCursor
mov ax, 0 
int 33h 
mov ax, 1 
int 33h 
ret
endp resetAndShowCursor

proc getMouseLocation
mov ax, 3 
int 33h 
ret

endp getMouseLocation

proc setPixelAtMouseLocation
shr cx, 2
shl cx, 1    
cmp bx, 1
jne @@done
cmp cx, 250 
ja @@done 
cmp cx, 5
jbe @@done 

cmp dx, 190
ja @@done

cmp dx, 20
jbe @@done

call set_pixel
@@done:
ret
endp setPixelAtMouseLocation

proc mouse_loop
@@drawLoop:
;call escape
;jz @@done
call getMouseLocation
call setPixelAtMouseLocation
jmp @@drawLoop

@@done:
ret
endp mouse_loop

proc render
call init
;call cls
call draw_out_background
call draw_inner_background
call draw_bottom_wall
call draw_left_wall
call draw_right_wall
call draw_top_wall
;call author_print
call resetAndShowCursor
call mouse_loop
ret
endp render
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The code is incomplete, I can't assemble it. Please provide an assemblable [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Did you read http://www.dosbox.com/DOSBoxManual.html#SpeedHelp?

Comment: I didn't look at the code, but that is what you'll get if you only plot pixels. Just plot lines and it will look a lot better. To get real smooth drawings, you should use Bezier lines (or similar), but that is not so easy.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis How can I draw lines? (Not pixels)

Comment: @rkhb I've added the full code. Just call render. Thanks

Comment: Use a suitable algorithm that draws lines made out of pixels, e.g. [Bresenham's line algorithm](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/group/goa/mallinnus/lines/bresenh.html). Perhaps there are x86 assembler examples online, otherwise you will have to implement it yourself, or convert, say, a C example.

Comment: Example: http://www.intel-assembler.it/portale/5/bresenham-line-and-circle-algorithms/bresenham-line-and-circle-algorithms.asp (near the end of the page).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis But why you think it only identifies and paint just part of the pixels?

Comment: The mouse is updated only so many times per second. So it will have moved more than one pixel between each update. If you move very slowly, the difference may be 1 pixel, but otherwise, the gap will be larger. So you will have to use lines (or whatever) to connect the dots.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Thanks. Is there an option to draw a line directly without drawing each point of it?

Comment: Lines are made up of points (pixels). There is no way to draw a line without setting at least all the pixels on that line. But I don't really know your programming environment. Perhaps it has a function to draw lines already?

Comment: FWIW, if you want to write a *drawing* program, you will have to find a way to draw lines, (filled) circles, (filled) rectangles, etc. anyway.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Ok, I guess that I will draw a line as a sequence of pixels. But if some of the pixels are "missed" during a single draw, I think that there is no option to restore the "motion line" of the painter. Am I missing something?

Comment: If your algorithm is correct, nothing will be "missed". Just remember the previous point and draw a proper line from there to the current point. As I said, if you can't even draw a line, a *drawing* program will not be very useful. Have you thought of using another language than machine code/assembler to write your program?

Comment: I mean a case where only the 2 black dots were detected, but the user draw it with the green dot or the blue dot, as you can see here: [link](http://prntscr.com/ew3xqz)

Comment: @YairHaimson you have to read the mouse coordinates "enough" often to get enough points to reconstruct the user movement with reasonable accuracy. If you have only those two black points, then you will draw wrong line. If the user wants better precision, then many painting apps offer bezier/spline lines, where the user can edit all points/curving before "baking" the line with particular stroke into the image.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I'm now working on connecting the pixels with lines. But except that, I've noticed a more significant problem as you can see at the [link](http://prnt.sc/ew5glx): there is always a one-pixel gap between pixels on the X axis! even if I move the mouse very slowly. as you can see, this problem doe's not exist on the Y axis. any suggestions?

Comment: I guess your drawing routine is not working correctly. Otherwise I don't know what the problem might be. But that would be a new question, especially if you show the code there. Note that drawing horizontal or vertical lines alone is not enough. You must be able to draw from any point to any other point.